# bun not found in Docker, trying to do split base/build image

Tags: docker, nuxtjs3, bun

I'm trying to do an image of the base project of nuxt3 on production with bun.
However, after doing `docker compose up`, I get this error :

```
=> ERROR [build 2/5] RUN bun install --production                                                                                                                                  0.2s
------
 > [build 2/5] RUN bun install --production:
#12 0.154 /bin/sh: 1: bun: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bun install --production]: exit code: 127
ERROR: Service 'my-app' failed to build : Build failed
```

I don't really know what is this error, as I'm a beginner on nuxt and docker.

I have this Dockerfile :

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

ARG NODE_VERSION=18.14.2

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-slim as base

FROM oven/bun:1.0.0

ARG PORT=3000

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /src

# Build
FROM base as build

COPY --link package.json bun.lockb .
RUN bun install --production

COPY --link . .

RUN bun run build
RUN bun prune
```

And this is my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I try before with npm and it worked.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace below lines

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=18.14.2

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-slim as base

FROM oven/bun:1.0.0
```

with:

```
FROM oven/bun:latest AS base
```

---

Your issue is because you try to do `bun install` using the `base` image (which don't have `bun` and instead has `node`) and hence fails.

Both `node` and `bun` are two different JavaScript runtimes. So don't use them together.

---

Your second issue is `RUN bun install --production`.

If you check your `package.json` file, you shall see `nuxt` is set as `devDependencies`, which are not installed when using `--production` flag.

So replace that with:

```
RUN bun install
```

Comment: I try it and I got another error : ```=> ERROR [build 2/5] RUN bun install --production                                                                                                                                  
------
 > [build 2/5] RUN bun install --production:
#12 0.163 bun install v1.0.0 (822a00c4)
#12 0.166 /bin/bash: line 1: nuxt: command not found
#12 0.166 error: script "postinstall" exited with code 127
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bun install --production]: exit code: 127
ERROR: Service 'my-app' failed to build : Build failed```

Comment: Thats a different error. Do you have `nuxt` added in your `package.json`?

Comment: Yes, I have nuxt-app define

Comment: Do you have a github repo with the code? If yes, share that, so that I can take a look.

Comment: Yes, I did one : https://urlz.fr/nCjv

Comment: @CocraftGm Updated my answer to solve your second issue. Please check.

Comment: @CocraftGm, note that each question should be only about _one_ question. You should call your question solved and click the checkbox to accept an answer when the question you asked is fixed; whether you get a new or different problem is irrelevant: an answer isn't responsible for fixing every problem you have, only the problem you _actually asked about_.

Comment: @RobinThomas okay, I will check tomorrow, thanks you !

Answer (score 5):

To anyone who installed Bun manually:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

And got this error:

```
 > [build 2/5] RUN bun install 
#12 0.154 /bin/sh: 1: bun: not found
```

Just add this to your dockerfile instead of using just bun install:

```
RUN ~/.bun/bin/bun install
```

(:

Comment: you can use the BUN_INSTALL environment variable to set the install path. note that it appends `/bin` so if you want it located at `/usr/bin/bun` you can call:  `curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | BUN_INSTALL=/usr bash`